# Disable syntax hightlighting in vim only for specific buffer

Tags: vim

I want to disable syntax highlighting but only for a specific buffer. I tried using modeline at the end of the buffer:

```
#vim:syntax off:
```

and

```
#vim:set syntax=off:
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a space (minimally) between the comment symbols and vim for mode lines to be parsed. The first one is also missing an equals sign.

```
# vim:syntax=off:
```

Or

```
# vim:set syntax=off:
```

---

If you look at `:h modeline` you will see that there can be any leading text before vim: but there needs to be whitespace after that text.

The two forms fix the patterns

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}

[text]                  any text or empty
{white}                 at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|ex:}          the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
[white]                 optional white space
{options}               a list of option settings, separated with white space
                        or ':', where each part between ':' is the argument
                        for a ":set" command (can be empty)
```

Or

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|Vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]

[text]                  any text or empty
{white}                 at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|Vim:|ex:}     the string "vi:", "vim:", "Vim:" or "ex:"
[white]                 optional white space
se[t]                   the string "set " or "se " (note the space); When
                        "Vim" is used it must be "set".
{options}               a list of options, separated with white space, which
                        is the argument for a ":set" command
:                       a colon
[text]                  any text or empty
```

Comment: Also note that `syntax off` will turn off syntax highlighting for all the opened buffers, which may not be what you want. To turn off highlighting for the current buffer only, use `setlocal syntax=OFF`.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** Switch to the [manual mode](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0967/runtime/doc/usr_06.txt#L207-L215) (`:sy manual`), enable syntax highlighting with `:se syn=ON`.

What `:sy on` (`:syntax on`) does under the hood is sets the `'syn'` (`'syntax'`) option for [all the active buffers](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0967/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim#L40), and makes `vim` set the `'syn'` option for any [new files](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0967/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim#L32) you open. `:sy manual` [disables](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0967/runtime/syntax/manual.vim#L22) the latter automatic behavior. So to enable syntax highlighting for a buffer in the manual mode you've got to: `:se syn=ON`. To make it clear `:sy manual` doesn't affect the open buffers. They remain highlighted. But when you later do `:se syn=ON`, syntax highlighting is enabled for all the active buffers.

In other words if you're going to open a big file, you might want to do `:sy manual` before that. Then the file will open unhighlighted. If you open another file (you didn't open before in this `vim` instance, i.e. the inactive buffer doesn't exist) it will also open unhighlighted. To enable syntax for this (supposedly not big) buffer you'd do: `se syn=ON`. When you no longer need to work with the big file, you do: `:sy on`.